# Cannot connect from Classic ASP to SQL Server 2008 R2 using SQL Native Client (Windows 7 - IIS7)

Tags: sql-server-2008, iis-7, asp-classic, connection, sql-server-native-client

I'm able to connect to SQL server 2008 R2 when I use `Provider=SQLOLEDB` in my connection string. But when I use `Provider=SQLNCLI` in connection string I'm unable to connect.

> ADODB.Connection error '800a0e7a'
>
> Provider cannot be found. It may not
>   be properly installed.
>
> /test.asp, line 7

Code written within `test.asp` is below

```
<%
    Set cn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    'Doesn't work
    cn.Open "Provider=SQLNCLI;Server=remoteServer\SQL2008R2;Database=DB;UID=MyUser;PWD=pa55word;"  

    'Works Perfectly
    'cn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=remoteServer\SQL2008R2;Database=DB;UID=MyUser;PWD=pa55word;" 

    cn.CommandTimeout = 900
    cn.Close
    Response.write("dfjslkfsl")
%>
```

The SQL Server I'm trying to connect (from classic ASP Page within my IIS 7 on windows 7) is located on different server in a different network to which I'm connecting using VPN.

I tested sql native client by creating a sql native client System DSN connection to the said Sql server 2008 R2 (which is connected through VPN) from ODBC datasource administrator. And it got connected successfully.

These snaps are from my windows 7 system
[image: Appwiz.cpl snap]

[image: IIS 7 features]

[image]

- Windows 7
- IIS 7
- Classic ASP page (.asp)

Comment: this may help you http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008

Comment: Might sound silly but have you tried `provider=sqlncli10`?

Comment: @Shadow thats not silly. It solved my problem :). I had `provider=sqlncli` in my code. Thanks very much. You can put it as answer if you want to earn 25 reputation points from me.

Comment: Cheers @Ismail, done that. Glad it worked! :)

Comment: I thought SQL 2008 was Native Client 10 ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try changing the provider to `sqlncli10`:

```
cn.Open "Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=remoteServer\SQL2008R2;Database=DB;UID=MyUser;PWD=pa55word;"
```

Maybe the name is differet on your machine. :)

Comment: This answer saved me a ton of time

Comment: I used this question and answer to help understand the switch from SQLOLEDB to SQLNCLI10 in some Excel VBA code.  Now my SQL "With" statement works.

Answer (score 4):

For users having only Visual Studio 2012 installed can use `Provider=SQLNCLI11` as `SQLNCLI10` is not available for me on my fresh installed system.

```
cn.Open "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=remoteServer\SQL2008R2;Database=DB;UID=MyUser;PWD=pa55word;"
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to the VPN fact. Maybe the app acts as a different user who doesn't have access to the VPN.

Try to turn off anonymous Authentication in IIS and/or make the Application Pool identity be the same user you use to login to the Windows 7 machine and see if this fixes the problem.

Comment: +1 for nice pointers. Let me try them out tonight when I go home. Right now I'm in office network itself and using other system on which it works fine.

Answer (score -2):

Works perfectly fine:

```
"Provider=SQLNCLI;Server=xxxxxxxx;uid=sa;pwd=xxxxxx;database=xxxxxx;"
```

Comment: why are you copying the accepted answer (to several questions)?