# Shopping cart using ASP

Tags: asp-classic, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I don't know any bit of asp here except for the very basics. However, I would like to create a shopping cart based purely on ASP. The shopping cart should have the feature of updating automatically when a product is added. I have the html page ready with me but I have no idea of how to connect the database and carry out the operations using ASP. Please help me. It should be an ecommerce site.

Comment: have a look here; http://www.comersus.com/products/comersus-cart/, i think it's a bit much to ask if you're not custom to classic-asp.

Comment: actually I wanted to develop a site where users have their own accounts and can buy pc components. needed some help maybe on that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to connect to your database if you are using microsoft-access as database. Just change your database and table name

```
set conob = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conob.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
conob.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & server.MapPath("YourDatabaseName.mdb")
Set rsuni = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
sqlStr="select * from Student_Entry"

rsuni.open sqlStr,conob
```

If you are using sql server then go to [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216151/cannot-connect-from-classic-asp-to-sql-server-2008-r2-using-sql-native-client-w). There are answers posted  before